# How to see number of people who visit a site every day on graduated sites?

Tags: support, site-visits

I've been wanting to see the number of people who visit a graduated site every day. (The sidebar that contains this info is only visible on beta sites.)

The help page for the "access to site analytics" does not clearly state whether you can see the number of people who visit a site each day. Do I need the "access to site analytics" privilege, or is there a way without it?

Comment: On *beta sites only*, there's a sidebar on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click here >>> https://stackexchange.com/sites

The 3rd column from the right reads *visits/day*

Comment: Styled just like spam :)